# More Flexible International Searches

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I'm looking for extremely flexible flight search engines.  Here are the features I'd like to be able to utilize:

- More flexible date search, specifically, I want to be gone between 7
  and 12 days, but I'm good with leaving and arriving any time within
  two months. I can search on a site like kayak, but only within a few days, and it won't preserve my trip length.
- "Super long" layovers, rather than 3-8 hours in a layover, I'd like a longer layover, more like 16-48 hours.  Sometimes these pop up in the searches, but I can't figure out how to locate them specifically.

Is there any site that works well and has more options than a site like kayak?  For what it is worth, I'm looking to travel from DSM to RIO in September or October of this year.

Comment: The higher search flexibility comes at the cost of maximizing your chances to find the best price. I've noticed on Kayak that if I do a range search, I sometimes don't find the lowest price as I would if I did searched on specific days.

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate, yet the linked question does not actually answer what I am asking for.  The link refers to searching with a range of a few days on either end, not weeks, and does nothing with allowing for searching for long layovers.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried http://www.skyscanner.net? If it doesn't have the features you require, we'd be interested to hear from you.

In addition to Kayak, there's also Google Flights at https://www.google.com/flights/.